# Nested key/val pair in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-components

Below is the data:

```
this.info = { 
  key1: {
    'name': 'xyz', 
    link:'www.google.com'
  },
  age: 21,
  address: '.....'
}
```

I am using component and passing this data and using below code in template:

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key,value) in $ctrl.info">
  <td>{{key}}:</td>
  <td ng-if="value.link!==undefined"><a ui-sref={{value.link}}> {{value.name}}</a></td>
  <td ng-if="value.link==undefined">{{value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Basically i want to display values as hyperlink if link attribute is present in value else plain simple value.It is working fine for numeric values and values with link attribute but for string/rest it says invalid state ' ' . Looks like 
ng-if="value.link!==undefined" part is not getting executed properly.It is always true if value is string. Not able to get my logic working.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try ng-if="!value.hasOwnProperty('link')" instead.

Comment: Do you want to check if your `link` attribute have valid link address ?

Comment: @disperse Worked.. Thanks

Comment: I think `ui-sref` is just for ui router states so `ng-href ` would be a better choice for url links

Answer (score -1):

You are not showing what the value of link is if there is no link. But if I understand your question correctly you should be checking for `ng-if="value.link` and `ng-if="!Value.link"`